# Принудительное освобождение памяти

Tags: .net, c#

Имеется код, который использует буфер для обмена между двумя сущностями.

```
byte[] data = someInst.getData();
otherInst.setData( data, data.length);
```

Обмен очень интенсивный. Как я понял, .NET не успевает освободить память выделенную в getData(). Возможно ли после метода setData() вызвать принудительную сборку мусора?

Comment: если обе сущности Ваши, то может выделить один раз один буфер (может два) и просто одна сущность его заполняет, другая использует. GC даже дергаться не будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блин, ну опять двадцать пять. Нет смысла вызывать сборку мусора. Если объекты действительно никем не используются, то они будут и так уничтожены, а если нет - то не будут, что бы вы там не делали.

Если так жутко хочется пнуть сборку мусора, то можете вызывать [Collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xe0c2357.aspx). Но это не имеет смысла.

**UPD** .NET не может не успевать делать сборку. Ваш вопрос вызван непонимаением концепции и модели памяти рантаймов с автоматической сборкой мусора. Если куча переполняется, то перед тем как её увеличивать он наверняка попытается мусор собрать. А раз куча растёт и растёт, то это значит, что вы не освобождаете ресурсы. Если не верите, то попробуйте добавить вызов Collect и увидите.

Comment: Вы не правы. В моем приложении пересылка подобного рода используется очень интенсивно, и буквально через пять минут работы, приложение съедает всю память ПК. .NET просто не успевает вызвать сборку столько, сколько надо.

Comment: ТВы хотите сказать, что .NET не выполняет сборку и выделяет память, пока всё не лопнет? Ни за что не поверю. Скорее всего у вас просто утечка где-то.

Comment: К тому же, если вы гоняете в большом количестве какие-то гигантские массивы, то это наверняка признак ошибки в дизайне приложения.

Comment: Я в профайлере посмотрел. Память под переменную data выделяется и не освобождается.

Comment: Конечно она не освободится сразу. Но если вы действительно отпускаете ссылку, то объект будет уничтожен и сборка когда-нибудь осуществится и это будет раньше, чем будут израсходованы все системные ресурсы. А раз не освобождается, то значит ссылки всё ещё живые. К сожалению, ваш код здесь слишком мал, чтобы понять что-то.

Comment: У меня была программа, которая при отсутствии явной сборки мусора после обработки большого массива данных падала с OutOfMemoryException при запросе следующего массива данных. А явный вызов GC.Collect() перед запросом второго массива исправлял ситуацию.

Comment: В таком случае, это баг в .NET.